# Clicking on IconButton from Material UI causing Errors with Ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working with Material UI and I am not understanding an error that I am receiving. The error occurs every time that I click on the IconButton component to open up a menu. The menu opens but I get this error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `ForwardRef(Menu)`.
    in MenuItems (at OMSDashboard.js:67)
    in ul (created by ForwardRef(List))
    in ForwardRef(List) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)) (created by ForwardRef(MenuList))
    in ForwardRef(MenuList) (created by ForwardRef(Menu))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Transition)
    in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Grow))
    in ForwardRef(Grow) (created by Unstable_TrapFocus)
    in Unstable_TrapFocus (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Portal) (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Modal) (created by ForwardRef(Popover))
    in ForwardRef(Popover) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Popover)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Popover)) (created by ForwardRef(Menu))
    in ForwardRef(Menu) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Menu)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Menu)) (at OMSDashboard.js:63)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Toolbar))
    in ForwardRef(Toolbar) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Toolbar)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Toolbar)) (at OMSDashboard.js:54)
    in header (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by ForwardRef(AppBar))
    in ForwardRef(AppBar) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar)) (at OMSDashboard.js:53)
    in OMSDashboard (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:16)
    in Switch (at App.js:13)
    in App (at src/index.js:8)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:7)
```

I am not sure what this is referring to. I have provided the code below:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, Fragment} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1
    },
    flex: {
      flex: 1
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginLeft: -12,
      marginRight: 20
    },
    appBar: {
      marginLeft: '20px',
      height: '75px'
    },
    toolbarMargin: {
      minHeight: '75px'
    }
  })
);

const OMSDashboard = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchor, setAnchor] = useState(null);
  const MenuItems = () => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <MenuItem >Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem >My Account</MenuItem> 
        <MenuItem >Logout</MenuItem>  
      </Fragment>
  )};

  return (
      <Fragment>
        <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              className={classes.menuButton}
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="Menu"
              onClick={e => setAnchor(e.currentTarget)}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              anchorEl={anchor}
              open={Boolean(anchor)}
            >
              <MenuItems  />
            </Menu>
            <Typography
              variant="h1"
              color="inherit"
              className={classes.flex}
            >
              DashBoard
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Menu</Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <div className={classes.toolbarMargin} />
          <ul>
            {new Array(500). fill(null).map((v, i) => (
              <li key={i}>{i}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default OMSDashboard;
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's referring on anchor's default value of null. Try removing the null.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I tried to enter nothing in the useState and empty string ('') neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Spotted the issue... the problem is not the IconButton itself, it comes from the "relationship" between `Menu` and `MenuItem`.

Unfortunately, the only working solution I could find and test successfully was about `React.forwardRef` for Menu, MenuItem and the IconButton...

1st create your `forwardedRef` components:

```
const CustomMenuButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
        <IconButton {...props} buttonRef={ref}>
            { props.children }
        </IconButton>));

export default CustomMenuButton;
```

```
const CustomMenu = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (<Menu ref={ref} {...props}>{props.children}</Menu>));

export default CustomMenu;
```

** Note: ** for this MenuItem you'll have to use `innerRef` instead:

```
const CustomMenuItem = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (<MenuItem innerRef={ref} {...props}>{props.children}</MenuItem>));

export default CustomMenuItem;
```

2nd: Apply those ones in your code instead:

```
return (
      <Fragment>
        <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
          <Toolbar>
            <CustomMenuButton
              className={classes.menuButton}
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="Menu"
              onClick={e => setAnchor(e.currentTarget)}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </CustomMenuButton>
            <CustomMenu
              anchorEl={anchor}
              open={Boolean(anchor)}
            >
              {/* Does MenuItems "map" the MenuItem inside? */}
              {/* In that case, use CustomMenuItem instead for each one! */}

              <MenuItems  />

            </CustomMenu>
            <Typography
              variant="h1"
              color="inherit"
              className={classes.flex}
            >
              DashBoard
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Menu</Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <div className={classes.toolbarMargin} />
          <ul>
            {new Array(500). fill(null).map((v, i) => (
              <li key={i}>{i}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default OMSDashboard;
```